# how to align numeric filed to right using itextsharp(pdfstamper)

Tags: c#, pdf, alignment, itext

Please refer my code where i am writing values on pdf. But i want to align numeric fields to the right.
Is there any property/method for that. I am using this property `PdfFormField.MK_CAPTION_RIGHT` but it is not working.

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(outputPath);
string fontsfolder1 = @"D:\ItextSharp\Fonts\acmesab.TTF";
var pdfStamper1 = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputPath3, FileMode.Create));
BaseFont customfont1 = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontsfolder, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
   AcroFields af = pdfStamper1.AcroFields;
   List<BaseFont> list1 = new List<BaseFont>();
   list.Add(customfont1);
   iTextSharp.text.Font bold1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(customfont1, 6, 0, BaseColor.BLACK);
   af.SubstitutionFonts = list;
   foreach (var field1 in af.Fields)
   {
            af.SetFieldProperty(field1.Key, "textalignment", PdfFormField.MK_CAPTION_RIGHT, null);
     af.SetField(field1.Key, "123");
   }
     pdfStamper1.FormFlattening = false;
     pdfStamper1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you can do this directly using ItextSharp Property.But one way is to add the spaces to the left of the content,to do this you can get the Field Length and based on that length and length of the content, you can calculate the spaces to be added to the left of the content.it will automatically put your content to the right side of the PDF field.hope this way can help you solve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can align the text by using the ShowTextAligned method which takes an alignment parameter, like this:

```
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT,"Text is left aligned",200,800,0);
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT,"Text is right aligned",200,788,0);
```

where cb is `PdfContentByte`

[For Detail](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-ii/)

Comment: thank you for reply....As I see the link they have used writer...but here i use Pdfstamper...how can i use this property with pdfstamper?